# Tensorflow - mapping python function with two parameters

Tags: python, tensorflow

Hi I have a python function where I am trying to map a tensor to. I essentially need to run every element through the function. I am not sure how to map the two parameters to this function. Not only this but even when I remove the second parameter it gives me an error:

```
TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'list'
```

Here is my full code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def sigmoid(x, derivative = False):
    if derivative == True:
        return (1.0/(1+math.exp(-x))) * (1.0 - (1.0/(1+math.exp(-x))))
    return 1.0/(1+math.exp(-x))

# build computational graph
a = tf.placeholder('float', None)

result = tf.map_fn(sigmoid, [a] , tf.float32)

# initialize variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# create session and run the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    print sess.run(result, feed_dict={a: [2,3,4]})

# close session
sess.close()
```

I was following this: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func

**EDIT**
I can do the exp function using tensorflows library:

```
def sigmoid(x, derivative = False):
    if derivative == True:
        return (1.0/(1+tf.exp(-x))) * (1.0 - (1.0/(1+tf.exp(-x))))
    return 1.0/(1+tf.exp(-x))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why cant you use the `tf.nn.sigmoid()` function?.

```
def sigmoid(x, derivative = False):
   if derivative == True:
       return tf.nn.sigmoid(x) * (1.0 - tf.nn.sigmoid(x))
   return tf.nn.sigmoid(x)
```

If you want to call a `numpy` function in the graph, you can use `tf.py_func` (The code will be executed in CPU only):

```
def sigmoid(x, derivative = False):
if derivative == True:
    return (1.0/(1+np.exp(-x))) * (1.0 - (1.0/(1+np.exp(-x))))
return 1.0/(1+np.exp(-x))

# build computational graph
a = tf.placeholder('float', None)

result = tf.py_func(sigmoid, [a, True] , tf.float32)
```

Comment: This will work, but how can I get it to use the derivative? As in how can I pass two parameters into the function?

Comment: Just call, result = sigmoid(a, derivative = True)?

Comment: Thanks, How about if I needed to do an operation that required numpy. From what I understand I would not be able to do this?

Comment: I thought that the py_func did this?
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func

Comment: @kevin you are right, we can use `py_func` to call numpy functions. Updated the answer.